# C# Increment operator (++) question:Why am i getting wrong output?

Tags: c#

I have a simple c# console application but i am getting wrong output why?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 100;
        for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++)
        {
            i = i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Old question about the same construction in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831341/why-does-this-go-into-an-infinite-loop

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post-increment Operator Overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668763/post-increment-operator-overloading)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`i++` is an expression which returns `i`, then increments it.

Therefore, `i = i++` will evaluate `i`, increment `i`, then assign `i` to the *original* value, before it was incremented.

You need to use `++i`, which will return the incremented value.

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing that you really want an explanation as to why it doesn't work as expected, rather than to actually get the result since you can get that by setting `i` equal to 200 in the first place.

The postincrement operator is applied after a temporary copy of the variable is created.  The temporary is used for operations in the statement then the assignment is performed, thus your loop is equivalent to:

```
    for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++)
    {
        j = i;
        i++;
        i = j;
    }
```

Since that's the case, the increment is basically discarded and `i` is never actually incremented.

Answer (score 5):

```
i = i++;
```

This sets i to the old value of i, then increments it.  I think you want:

```
i++;
```

Or better yet if your compiler is lame and doesn't optimize the return:

```
++i;
```

Cheers.

Comment: Or, even better, `i += 2`. In C/++, `i = i++;` is explicitly undefined.

Answer (score 4):

The line `i = i++;` writes twice to the variable i. The post increment is executed first, but then the assignment statement overwrites it.

Try just `i++;`

Answer (score 3):

Just use i++, not i = i++.