# Issue in Creating Date cell in Excel using OpenXml in C#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have a requirement to export a data table to excel file.I had done it using DocumentFormat.OpenXml. But i could'nt get date (year-month-date) filter in exported excel, as my cell is taken as string,not an excel date cell. I got it using interop.dll.But it is time consuming. I have above 30000 records. Any help is appreciated. My code is as below:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds=new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(GetData());
        GenerateExcel(ds);
    }

public void GenerateExcel(DataSet data)
    {
        var Memstream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(Memstream, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {
            var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();
            workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();
            workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets();
            WorkbookStylesPart wbsp = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
            wbsp.Stylesheet = CreateStylesheet1();
            wbsp.Stylesheet.Save();

            uint sheetId = 0;

            foreach (System.Data.DataTable table in data.Tables)
            {
                var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                var sheetData = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData();
                sheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData);
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>();
                string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);
                int k = sheets.ChildElements.Count;
                string bsd = sheets.InnerText;
                string jknkj = sheets.InnerXml;
                sheetId = sheetId++;
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet sheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = table.TableName };
                sheets.Append(sheet);

                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row headerRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();

                List<String> columns = new List<string>();
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {
                    columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

                        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                        cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                        cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                        headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
                }

                sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

                foreach (DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
                {
                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();
                    foreach (String col in columns)
                    {
                        DateTime dDate;
                        if (DateTime.TryParse(dsrow[col].ToString(), out dDate))
                        {
                            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.Number;
                            cell.StyleIndex = 164;
                            cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dDate.ToOADate().ToString());
                            newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                            cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString());
                            newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                        }
                    }
                    sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
                }
            }
            workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            workbook.Close();
        }
        string filename=@"D:\\Excel Samples\file_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyyHH-mm-ss") + ".xlsx";
        FileStream file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        Memstream.WriteTo(file);
        file.Close();
        Memstream.Close();
    }
 private Stylesheet CreateStylesheet1()
    {
        Stylesheet ss = new Stylesheet();

        Fonts fts = new Fonts();
        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Font ft = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Font();
        FontName ftn = new FontName();
        ftn.Val = "Calibri";
        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.FontSize ftsz = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.FontSize();
        ftsz.Val = 11;
        ft.FontName = ftn;
        ft.FontSize = ftsz;
        fts.Append(ft);
        fts.Count = (uint)fts.ChildElements.Count;

        Fills fills = new Fills();
        Fill fill;
        PatternFill patternFill;
        fill = new Fill();
        patternFill = new PatternFill();
        patternFill.PatternType = PatternValues.None;
        fill.PatternFill = patternFill;
        fills.Append(fill);
        fill = new Fill();
        patternFill = new PatternFill();
        patternFill.PatternType = PatternValues.Gray125;
        fill.PatternFill = patternFill;
        fills.Append(fill);
        fills.Count = (uint)fills.ChildElements.Count;

        Borders borders = new Borders();
        Border border = new Border();
        border.LeftBorder = new LeftBorder();
        border.RightBorder = new RightBorder();
        border.TopBorder = new TopBorder();
        border.BottomBorder = new BottomBorder();
        border.DiagonalBorder = new DiagonalBorder();
        borders.Append(border);
        borders.Count = (uint)borders.ChildElements.Count;

        CellStyleFormats csfs = new CellStyleFormats();
        CellFormat cf = new CellFormat();
        cf.NumberFormatId = 0;
        cf.FontId = 0;
        cf.FillId = 0;
        cf.BorderId = 0;
        csfs.Append(cf);
        csfs.Count = (uint)csfs.ChildElements.Count;

        uint iExcelIndex = 164;
        NumberingFormats nfs = new NumberingFormats();
        CellFormats cfs = new CellFormats();

        cf = new CellFormat();
        cf.NumberFormatId = 0;
        cf.FontId = 0;
        cf.FillId = 0;
        cf.BorderId = 0;
        cf.FormatId = 0;
        cfs.Append(cf);

        NumberingFormat nf;
        nf = new NumberingFormat();
        nf.NumberFormatId = iExcelIndex++;
        nf.FormatCode = StringValue.FromString("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        //nf.FormatCode = StringValue.FromString("mm-d-yy h:mm:ss AM/PM");
        nfs.Append(nf);
        cf = new CellFormat();
        cf.ApplyNumberFormat = true;
        cf.NumberFormatId = nf.NumberFormatId;
        cf.FontId = 0;
        cf.FillId = 0;
        cf.BorderId = 0;
        cf.FormatId = 0;
        cfs.Append(cf);

        nf = new NumberingFormat();
        nf.NumberFormatId = iExcelIndex++;
        nf.FormatCode = "#,##0.0000";
        nfs.Append(nf);
        cf = new CellFormat();
        cf.NumberFormatId = nf.NumberFormatId;
        cf.FontId = 0;
        cf.FillId = 0;
        cf.BorderId = 0;
        cf.FormatId = 0;
        cf.ApplyNumberFormat = true;
        cfs.Append(cf);

        // #,##0.00 is also Excel style index 4
        nf = new NumberingFormat();
        nf.NumberFormatId = iExcelIndex++;
        nf.FormatCode = "#,##0.00";
        nfs.Append(nf);
        cf = new CellFormat();
        cf.NumberFormatId = nf.NumberFormatId;
        cf.FontId = 0;
        cf.FillId = 0;
        cf.BorderId = 0;
        cf.FormatId = 0;
        cf.ApplyNumberFormat = true;
        cfs.Append(cf);

        // @ is also Excel style index 49
        nf = new NumberingFormat();
        nf.NumberFormatId = iExcelIndex++;
        nf.FormatCode = "@";
        nfs.Append(nf);
        cf = new CellFormat();
        cf.NumberFormatId = nf.NumberFormatId;
        cf.FontId = 0;
        cf.FillId = 0;
        cf.BorderId = 0;
        cf.FormatId = 0;
        cf.ApplyNumberFormat = true;
        cfs.Append(cf);

        nfs.Count = (uint)nfs.ChildElements.Count;
        cfs.Count = (uint)cfs.ChildElements.Count;

        ss.Append(nfs);
        ss.Append(fts);
        ss.Append(fills);
        ss.Append(borders);
        ss.Append(csfs);
        ss.Append(cfs);

        CellStyles css = new CellStyles();
        CellStyle cs = new CellStyle();
        cs.Name = "Normal";
        cs.FormatId = 0;
        cs.BuiltinId = 0;
        css.Append(cs);
        css.Count = (uint)css.ChildElements.Count;
        ss.Append(css);

        DifferentialFormats dfs = new DifferentialFormats();
        dfs.Count = 0;
        ss.Append(dfs);

        TableStyles tss = new TableStyles();
        tss.Count = 0;
        tss.DefaultTableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9";
        tss.DefaultPivotStyle = "PivotStyleLight16";
        ss.Append(tss);

        return ss;
    }
```

Comment: A good way to figure this out is to open the result of your interop code in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool. That can show you 1) the underlying Open XML and 2) the Open XML SDK code to generate the workbook. For this, probably best to generate a workbook with just a few correct "dates" in it so that you don't have to wade through tons of material to find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your reply. I got the answer. By setting StyleIndex=1 instead of 164, i got solution. Hope this helps anyone..

Comment: You also have a bug on the line `sheetId = sheetId++;` - this doesn't do what you might expect as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4287920/3791802) - you probably just want `sheetId++;`