# int x = 10; x += x--; in .Net - Why?

Tags: c#, .net, operators

```
int x = 10;
x += x--;
```

In C#/.Net, why does it equal what it equals? *(I'm purposely leaving the answer out so you can guess and see if you're right)*

Comment: It behaves that way because you should never do anything like that, and as such the behavior is irrelevant.

Comment: i should not second guess myself. seemed obvious until i thought about it a second. my reasoning for thinking 20 was that the decrement did not happen until after the reference and then i started bumbling out thinking that the original reference would be decremented when the operation compeleted but it is a value type but but so i guess 19. silly me.

Comment: @Stefan - It isn't irrelevant to have a deep level of understanding about a language, even if you always write good code.  You may not apply the entirety of your knowledge, but you'll be more confident when someone needs help.

Comment: @Sky: it has nothing to do with "value type" as much as order of operations (the assignment happens after the decrement, which happens after resolution of RHS value which happens after addition.)

Comment: After Jon Skeets explanation, I'm curious to know how many compilers would optimize out the --.

Comment: @Stuart B: I'd just refactor to avoid the issue. If you have to really think about a fundamental part of your programming language to get it to work, you're probably not doing it right, or there's a better language suited for the job.

Comment: Questions like this should be called clay pigeons... perfect for Skeet shooting.

Comment: @Stefan - some people just don't appreciate the purely academic aspects of programming, I suppose. ;)

Comment: @jimmy, which was my instant first thought and simply got trapped. silly me. thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between X = X++; vs X++;?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226002/whats-the-difference-between-x-x-vs-x)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Look at this statement:

```
x += x--;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
x = x + x--;
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
int a1 = x; // a1 = 10, x = 10
int a2 = x--; // a2 = 10, x = 9
x = a1 + a2; // x = 20
```

So `x` is 20 afterwards - and that's guaranteed by the spec.

What's *also* pretty much guaranteed, although not by the spec, is that anyone using such code will be attacked by their colleagues. Yes, it's good that the result is predictable. No, it's not good to *use* that kind of code.

Comment: No fair...Skeet shouldn't be allowed to answer these questions. :P

Comment: @CAbbott - unfortunately no one else appears to understand the difference between x-- and --x!

Comment: I want to know if Jon did this from memory.

Comment: Sure, why not, but we all will loose the thrill and energy we put into search for the answer to come up earlier than Jon Skeet. And that is the all fun part.!!

Comment: What if he used --x instead? Is that also guaranteed by the spec?

Comment: @Tom: Yes, I did. I checked it afterwards, admittedly. I did have to check that you'd specified `x` as `int` though... the first "equivalent to..." would be very slightly different if `x` were a `byte` even though the result would be the same in this case.

Comment: @Justin: Yes, that would be guaranteed to produce 19 - the value of a2 in the expansion would have been 9. You can get to 18 if you change it to `x = --x + x;`.

Comment: +1 for "...anyone using such code will be attacked by their colleagues..."

Answer (score 15):

Jon is of course right.

A good way to think about this is to remember:

1) subexpressions are always evaluated *left to right*. Period. Evaluation of a subexpression may induce a side effect.

2) execution of operators is always done in the order indicated by parentheses, precedence and associativity. Execution of operators may induce a side effect.

The "x" to the left of the += is the leftmost subexpression, and therefore rule (1) applies. Its value is computed first -- 10.

The x-- to the right of the += is the next one in left-to-right order, so it is evaluated next.  The value of x-- is 10, and the side effect is that x becomes 9. This is as it should be, because -- is of higher precedence than +=, so its side effect runs first.

Finally, the side effect of += runs last.  The two operands were 10 and 10, so the result is to assign 20 to x.

I get questions about this all the time. Remember, the rules are very straightforward: subexpressions left-to-right, operators in precedence order, period.

In particular, note that the commonly-stated reasoning "the -- operator is postfix and therefore runs after everything else" is incorrect reasoning. I discuss why that is incorrect in the articles below.

Here are some articles I've written on this subject:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/precedence/default.aspx

Comment: Addition is a sequence point in C#?  You're allowing people to write code without understanding sequence points.  Surely the end of the world is at hand.

Answer (score 14):

20; the "--" doesn't happen until after everything gets evaluated, and that value is overwritten by the left-hand side of the equals.

Comment: Though you've got the right answer, the logic that got you there is incorrect. The "doesn't happen until after everything gets evaluated" is misleading. In particular, the decrement happens before the assignment of 9 to x, which happens before the addition of 10 and 10, which happens before the assignment of 20 to x. The calculation of the decrement happens before one addition and two assignments, so it cannot be correct to say that it doesn't happen until *everything* gets evaluated.

Answer (score 10):

From the [specs 7.13.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691316%28VS.71%29.aspx)

> If the return type of the selected operator is implicitly convertible to the type of x, the operation is evaluated as x = x op y, except that x is evaluated only once.

So your statement is equivalent to `x = x + x--;` which is evaluated in left-to-right order and gives the answer 20.

Note that there is also a difference between `--x` and `x--` here. If you had written `x += --x;` this would be equivalent to `x = x + --x`; then you would get 19. This is because the value of x is decremented and the resulting value is used in the expression (unlike `x--` where the original value of x is used in the expression).

This expression `x = x + --x + x` will give 28 because the <s>third time</s>fourth time (see comments) x is evaluated it is 9.

Comment: Maybe you meant 20? 10 would be really surprising..;)

Comment: @Francesco: Typo, fixed. Now I added one more paragraph and *that* 10 is actually meant to be a 10.

Comment: Though the answer you came up with in the last paragraph is correct, your explanation doesn't quite make sense. The decrement cannot be done *before* x is evaluated because obviously the value computed by decrement depends on the evaluation of x! Rather, the right way to say this is that the value of the expression --x is the value that was assigned to x *after* the decrement. That is, the sequence of events is: evaluate x (10), evaluate x again (10), subtract one (9), assign 9 to x, add 10 and 9 (19), assign 19 to x. There are two evaluations of x and they both happen up front.

Comment: @Eric: Yes, you're right - the word "evaluated" was the wrong word to use there. Thanks for the correction. I've rephrased in my own words. Hopefully it's OK now.

Comment: Better, but still not perfect. You mean the *fourth* time x is evaluated in "x=x+--x+x" it is 9. First x is evaluated on the left hand side of the = to determine the location of the storage; this has no side effects and its value is not used, but it is an evaluation. Then it is evaluated on the right hand side of the = as 10. Then it is evaluated again as 10, 10-1 is computed, and 9 is assigned to x, and 9 is the result of the operation. Then, the *fourth* time x is evaluated, now it is 9.

Comment: For example, suppose instead we had T I<T>(T t){Console.WriteLine(t); return t;} and class Q { public int x; } and you said I(q).x = I(q).x + --I(q).x + I(q).x; -- you'd expect four lines to be written. The computation of the location of the storage can induce a side effect.  Note that when you say I(q).x += 123, the side effect only happens once; we do not actually expand this to I(q).x = I(q).x + 123;

Comment: @Eric: Yes, that point about the number of evaluations is actually mentioned in the quote from the specs at the start of my answer. And thanks for your patience in correcting these errors in posts here. I'll try to get this right next time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 20. And Tom, you really aren't as surprised as your questions seems to imply, right? And to those of you who are assuming the answer is 19 - I think you're confused with  x += --x;

Comment: What they're confused about is probably not --x, but rather, whether the side effect of "decrement x" happens before or after the computation of the left-hand side of the += operator. In language where x+=x-- is evaluated right-to-left, you first compute x--, which is 10, and assign 9 to x. Then you compute the left hand side, which is now 9. And now you add 9 to 10 and assign that to x, so, 19. C# guarantees that expressions are evaluated left-to-right. C++ does not; a C++ compiler can evaluate this right-to-left if it chooses, and both 19 and 20 are legal results.