# Why is `i += i++` 1 in C and 0 in C#?

Tags: c#, c, postfix-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

There was a very nice question on Stack overflow.

[For i = 0, why is (i += i++) equal to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516689/if-i-0-why-is-i-i-0-in-c)

But when I tried out the same code in C, it gave different results:

```
int i = 0;          
i += i++;          // 1 in C and 0 in C#
printf("%d", i);
```

But the following:

```
i = i++ + i;       // 1 in C and 1 in C#
i += i++ + i;      // 1 in C
```

In C# it evaluates the `++` and `=+` operators, first by assigning `tempVar` for each fo them and doing the operation on the `tempVars`. How does C implements it? Or is different by architecture?

Comment: Because undefined behavior is undefined?

Comment: The C++ standard, in their infinite wisdom, made the order expressions are evaluated undefined.

Comment: Yep, the behavior is undefined.  It's not specified whether the `+=` or the `++` will be evaluated first.  It could vary even within a single compiler.

Comment: Because Microsoft dictated that that's how C# behaves while in C or C++, there is no such rule forced down the implementers' throat.

Comment: @Hot Licks: "It's not specified whether the += or the ++ will be evaluated first." --- actually it's not a problem at all. The operators precedence clearly states `++` will be evaluated first

Comment: @zerkms - Not really.  Precedence is not the same as evaluation order.

Comment: The question is confusing. The title says `i = i++`, but the actual test case is `i = i++ + i` (where it really is just undefined behavior). I'm going to edit the title.

Comment: @zerkms Could you in future formulate that differently? There are so many people led to believe that operator precedence determines order of evaluation that your comment may exacerbate the misconception. It's the fact that `i++` is one operand of `+=` that requires `i++` to be evaluated before `+=`.

Comment: @zneak `i = i++` is also just undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: the formulation is perfectly clear. In this case undefined behaviour is caused by a sequence point (two modifications between 2 sequence points) not operator precedence. "It's the fact that i++ is one operand of += that requires i++ to be evaluated before +=" --- it's the fact because of operator precedence, nothing else.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: "i = i++ is also just undefined behaviour." --- right, and again it still has nothing to do with "it's not specified what operator `=` or `++` is evaluated first", it's again caused by 2 value modifications between sequence points.

Comment: @zerkms Yes. And I assumed that you knew that. But I have seen the idea that evaluation order were directly determined by operator precedence (e.g. that in `x && y++` the `y++` must be evaluated first because of precedence) so often here, that I fear your statement may deepen such confusion. If you don't omit the mention of the grouping that is determined by precedence, I hope that would be less amenable to deepen the confusion.

Comment: @zerkms The other thing was a reply to zneak's "but the actual test case is `i = i++ + i` (where it really is just undefined behavior)", not to you.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: "The other thing was a reply to zneak's" --- oh, okay. I'm used to seeing my nickname misspelled so often so I reply to anything started with `z` lol ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C standard does not specify an order of evaluation. It is left to the compiler implementation.

Comment: Order of evaluation of what exactly?

Comment: As you said in your comment, it is not known whether += or ++ is evaluated first

Comment: That's not important, because in the test case, the expression is `i++ + i` (contrary to what is stated in the question title). Which is evaluated first _is_ undefined.

Comment: @igon: I didn't say that. It's known which is evaluated first - `++`, because of operator precedence. Not an answer?

Comment: I guess, although I see that the question has been closed...

Comment: It is not just unspecified, the C standard explicitly says that the  result is  undefined. Having an undefined part in your program makes it invalid, and anything at all can happen.