# Why Don't "a=a++" Operation Increase The Value "a"

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If i == 0, why is (i += i++) == 0 in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516689/if-i-0-why-is-i-i-0-in-c)

I know this is not a logic implementation and I know I should use prefix ++ but I am curious about this code:

```
int a = 1;
a = a++;
Console.Write(a);
```

I expect that the result is 2 but it is not. Why is the resut 1? 
After `a` has been equilized to `a`, the value of `a` increased. But it seems ++ operation executed in another dimension :)

Comment: How many versions will be ask of this type question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Putting `++` *after* the `a` tells it to return the *old* value, *then* increment. At the same time, the incrementing happens *before* the assignment, so you lose the old value. Here is equivalent code:

```
int a = 1;
int temp_old_a = a; //temp_old_a is 1
a = temp_old_a + 1; //increments a to 2, this assignment is from the ++
a = temp_old_a; //assigns the old 1 value thus overwriting, this is from your line's assignment `a =` operator
Console.Write(a); //1
```

So you can see how it ultimately, throws away the incremented value. If on the other hand you put the `++` *before* the `a`:

```
int a = 1;
a = ++a;
Console.Write(a); //2
```

It acts like:

```
int a = 1;
int temp_old_a = a;
temp_old_a = temp_old_a + 1;
a = temp_old_a; //assigns the incremented value from the ++
a = temp_old_a; //assigns again as per your original line's assignment operator `a =`
Console.Write(a); //2
```

In this case, it usually doesn't make sense to reassign a variable when having it incremented as part of the expression. You're almost always better off just simply incrementing it:

```
int a = 1;
a++; //or ++a, but I find a++ is more typical
Console.Write(a); //2
```

It's usually more standard to see code like that and far less confusing (as you've found out).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I was just curious about it.

Answer (score 5):

`a++` is a *post-increment*, and that's the way it works. It behaves *as if* incrementing the variable *after* returning its value. Actually it increments its value but then returns the previous value.

`++a` on the other hand is *pre-increment*, which will behave as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Becouse `a++` is post-increment - first return value and then increase it. In this case you should use only

```
int a=1;
a++;
Console.Write(a);
```

or

```
int a = 1;
a = ++a;
Console.Write(a);
```

`++a` is pre-increment - first increase value and then return increased value.

Answer (score 0):

As a note: some languages accept the following syntax:

```
a = ++a
```

which would work as you suggested, incrementing a first, and returning it afterwards :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the ++ operand used as postfix increments the variable only after its value has been used.
If you use the ++ operand as prefix, the variable is incremented before its value is used.

For example:

> ### Case 1: postfix usage
>
> `int a = 1;`
>
> `int b;`
>
> `b = a++;`
>
> ### Case 2: prefix usage
>
> `int a = 1;`
>
> `int b;`
>
> `b = ++a;`

In "case 1" the b variable will be assigned with value 1 and in "case 2" with value 2.