# Why does this expression i+=i++ differs from Java and C?

Tags: java, c

I know about the prefix and posfix operation... the difference between ++i and i++ and so.

But I think I'm missing something here. Below you can find the code:

```
package test;

public class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int i=0;

        i+=i++;
        System.out.println(i); // Prints 0

        i = i + (i++);
        System.out.println(i); // Prints 0

        i = i + (i+1);
        System.out.println(i); // Prints 1

    }
}
```

So the output is:

```
0
0
1
```

I tried the same code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    int i=0;

    i+=i++;

    printf("%d", i);   // prints 1

    i = i + (i++);
    printf("%d", i);   // prints 3

    i = i + (i+1);
    printf("%d", i);   // prints 7
}
```

and the output was:

```
1
3
7
```

Why `i+=i++` doesn't increment `i` while the same code in C it increments the values?

Comment: Pick a tag: C or Java. That will determine whether this gets 100 upvotes or downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: Post your c too. The Java seems correct

Comment: For C this would be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060747/sequence-points-and-order-of-evaluation. It strongly smells like Java, though.

Comment: Find a page about your language of choice's operators and their precedence; then compute the result!

Comment: For java, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570589/java-i-operation-explanation and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x

Comment: @fge I think the question is - why is the result different, between the two languages.

Comment: There is a similar C# post that took a lot of attention http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516689/for-i-0-why-is-i-i-equal-to-0

Comment: @DavidWallace well yes, and the precedence of operators may differ from one language to the other -- if it is defined at all for C which is pretty liberal. For Java it is defined by the JLS so no problem there

Comment: @fge - and _that_ is the answer.

Comment: @Mysticial didn't understand the downvote sorry to not be a center of wisdom like you... it just called my attention

Comment: Precedence of operators only refers to parsing and is the same here. But semantics differ. In C it's undefined because of 2 unsynchronized accesses, in Java it's okay.

Comment: @Fede I didn't downvote. I was just poking fun at the fact that questions like this in Java tend to get hundreds of upvotes whereas the same question in C or C++ would get downvoted to -10, closed as stupid, and then deleted.

Comment: @Mysticial: In C or C++ it would probably just get closed as a duplicate of one of many, many identical questions, and everyone would move on.

Comment: @Mysticial ok, no worries. I was wonder of why I had different outputs for the same code. It wasn't obvious for me. People answers and comments helped me to be clear about it. I don't use to ask these kind of questions as you can see on my profile. Still don't understand why downvotes, it is only a questions and don't consider it so bad... seems there are many smart and intolerant people here

Comment: @Fede It's not a bad question (actually, it's a good question for first-timers). It's just that it's such a commonly asked question that the C and C++ folks have completely lost their patience and will destroy them on sight. I don't know how the Java community is able to handle it so differently.

Comment: Dupe: [why-x-x-gives-different-results-for-c-and-java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144359/why-x-x-gives-different-results-for-c-and-java?lq=1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Java**

In Java, the expression has a well-defined meaning. The [specification for the compound assignment operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.26.2) says:

> A compound assignment expression of the form *E1 op= E2* is equivalent to *E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2))*, where *T* is the type of *E1*, except that *E1* is evaluated only once.
>
> ...
>
> At run time, the expression is evaluated in one of two ways. If the left-hand operand expression is not an array access expression, then four steps are required:
>
> - First, the left-hand operand is evaluated to produce a variable. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression
>     completes abruptly for the same reason; the right-hand operand is not
>     evaluated and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, the value of the left-hand operand is saved and then the right-hand operand is evaluated. If this evaluation completes
>     abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the
>     same reason and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, the saved value of the left-hand variable and the value of the right-hand operand are used to perform the binary operation
>     indicated by the compound assignment operator. If this operation
>     completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly
>     for the same reason and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, the result of the binary operation is converted to the type of the left-hand variable, subjected to value set conversion
>     (§5.1.13) to the appropriate standard value set (not an
>     extended-exponent value set), and the result of the conversion is
>     stored into the variable.

So

```
i += i++;
```

is equivalent to

```
i = i + i++;
```

Because the value of the left-hand side is saved at the start, and then added to the value of right hand side, and because expression evaluation in Java is left-to-right, the modification of `i` caused by `i++` is overwritten by the subsequent assignment.

All this means that

```
i += i++;
```

is equivalent to

```
i += i;
```

**C**

In C the expression

```
i += i++;
```

has undefined behavior. And so anything might happen when you execute this code.  Which means that you cannot predict what value `i` will have after the statement completes.

And so it is entirely to be expected that the output from your C program differs from the output from your Java program.

Comment: Good to know, actually I though the opposite since java gave me 0 and and C gave what I expected.

Answer (score 7):

> Why does this expression i+=i++ differs from Java and C?

`i+=i++` is the same as `i = i + i++`

In Java (and C#) it is *required* that this be computed left-to-right. That is:

```
left = i;           // left of +
right = i;          // right of +, original value 
incr = right + 1;   // incremented value
i = incr;           // effect of ++
sum = left + right; // sum of left and right sides of +
i = sum;            // assign sum to i
```

In C it is *possible* but not *required* that this be computed left-to-right.  In particular, the assignments

```
left = i;
```

and

```
incr = right + 1;
i = incr;
```

can be done in the other order. That is, this ordering is *legal* in C:

```
right = i;          // right of +, original value 
incr = right + 1;   // incremented value
i = incr;           // effect of ++
left = i;           // left of +
sum = left + right; // sum of left and right sides of +
i = sum;
```

Which obviously gives a different result.  (This is not the only possible reordering, but it is a plausible one.)

So, C and Java are different here because *the program fragment isn't well-defined in C to begin with*. In Java it *is* well-defined, it is just bad style.

Comment: @Fede: You're welcome. You might also want to carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i/3346729#3346729 -- the question is about C# but applies pretty well to Java.

Answer (score 5):

`i+=i++` is the same as `i = i + i++`. Let `i` be zero as in your example.

Now this evaluates as follows:

`i = 0 + i++ //evaluate i++ to zero, then increment i by one`

`i = 0 + 0   //overwrite the value of i with 0 + 0`

in other words, you do increment it but immediately overwrite it with the old value.

Comment: thanks kviiri, so how C evaluates this, I expected java resolves it in the same way

Comment: @Fede, I know my Java far better than I do my C, but I believe this is undefined behavior. In other words, you may get different results different times when you run the program, or when using a different compiler.

Answer (score 1):

This breaks down into the following internal sequence:

```
int temp1 = i;
int temp2 = i + i;
i = temp1 + 1;
i = temp2;
```

(Remember that i++ is *post-increment* while ++i is *pre-increment*.)

Answer (score 0):

You are using an expression that has *undefined behavior*.

Specifically, the *order of operations* on the same operand within the same expression is not well-defined. When you mix in decrement operators, you end up with surprising results, because the compiler is free to rearrange the order that they occur.

Comment: In Java, it is defined.  In C, it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Java evaluation order is [from left to right](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1) and the [operands are evaluated before the operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.2). This means that when `i=0` the evaluation is as follows:

```
i+=i+1
is equivalent to:
i = i + (i++)

evaluating operators from left to right and knowing i=0
i = 0 + (i++)

evaluate i++. it returns 0 and assigns i=1
i = 0 + 0

evaluate 0+0=0
assign i=0, overwriting the previously assigned value of 1
```

The second expression in your Java code is equivalent to the first one, but the third one is different:

```
i = i + (i+1)

given that i=0, we evaluate left to right:

evaluate i as 0 and obtain:
i = 0 + (i+1)

evaluate i+1:
    evaluate i as 0 and obtain:
    0+1=1
thus we obtain:
i = 0 + 1
i = 1
```

Note that (i+1) has no side effects, it only returns the value of i+1 but does not change the value of i.

As for the C code, as far as I know, the execution order in this case is undefined, thus it is up to the compiler implementation to decide. I might be wrong with this one so please correct me.

Comment: Saying that the operators are evaluated before the operands is confusing; clearly if you add x + y then the operands -- x and y -- must be evaluated before the result of operator + is evaluated. Are you sure that's what you meant to say?

Comment: But if we have, for example, a + b + c, we could evaluate a, b and then a + b and then evaluate c and add it to the result.

Comment: Correct. Let's instead say `a * b + c`.  The `+` has two operands: `a*b` and `c`.  The *operands* of `+` are both evaluated *before* the `+`.  The `*` has two operands: `a` and `b`.  Again, the operands are evaluated *before* the operator.  Now, there is no requirement that the operand `c` of the `+` be evaluated before the `*`, but the `c` isn't even an operand of the `*`, so that's not relevant.

Comment: Right. Now I see it, I'm sorry. I meant *operands are evaluated before operators*. I edited my post, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at this as a Java question, because it does have a defined result. From time to time I get inspired to analyze one of these questions in terms of the Java Language Specification, especially [Chapter 15 - Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html).

First, `i+=i++;` with `i` initially 0.

`+=` is one of the [Compound Assignment Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.26.2). For `int` `i`, The statement is equivalent to `i = (int)(i+i++);`

To evaluate the `+` we must first evaluate its left hand side, value 0. Next we evaluate its right hand side, `i++`.

`++` is the [Postfix Increment Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.14.2). The key statement is "The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the variable before the new value is stored.", which is 0. The value `1` is stored to `i` as a side effect, but that does not matter because there will be an assignment to `i` before it is used again.

Now we evaluate 0+0. `+` is one of the [Additive Operators (+ and -) for Numeric Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.18.2). It's a nice simple int addition, result 0.

Finally, we finish the `+=` by doing a cast to `int` and an assignment as though it were the  [Simple Assignment Operator =](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.26.1), with no conversion needed because the right hand side type was `int`. `i` is now 0.

The second statement is the first one with the `+=` expanded and the `int` to `int` conversions dropped. Same result.

The difference for `i = i + (i+1);` is in the result for a simple addition, `+`. See, again, [Additive Operators (+ and -) for Numeric Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.18.2): "The binary + operator performs addition when applied to two operands of numeric type, producing the sum of the operands.". The statement assigns `0+(0+1)` to `i`.

Treating each of the three statements as equivalent to `i = i + (i + 1)`, getting 1, 3, 7, is well within the possibilities for reasonable C implementations.

Answer (score -1):

i++ will evaluate the i first so that why you get 0 after the operation finish and stack the value its will increment after.

so if you do this

```
int i = 0;
System.out.println(i++); = 0
System.out.println(i++); = 1
```

Comment: That is not what OP is asking. Also from "*I know about the prefix and posfix operation*" we can assume that OP knows main idea behind `i++`. Question is why code in Java returns `0,0,1` while same code in C `1,3,7`.

Comment: i don't think its wrong or bad answer logically that how java and C# work but in C the order of evaluation of subexpressions is unspecified so yeah he might understand the prefix and postfix but he should verify if the behavior is the same.

Comment: I am not saying your answer is untrue. I am saying that as it stays now it doesn't answer OP question because it doesn't say anything about undefined behaviour in C.

Comment: didn't downvote but I think it's because you put same i++ expressions while the 2nd one should be ++i

Comment: no worrie jsut a downvote but if you try System.out both like that it will output 0 and 1 you don't need to ++i on the second one