# Incrementing and decreasing i is not working properly

Tags: c#, operators, increment, decrement

The following two lines of code are not returning the same value. Any reason for that?

```
int i;

i = 1;
i = i + i++; //Returns 2, expecting 3
```

And

```
i = 1;
i = i++ + i; //Returns 3
```

Semantically, this should be the same `a + b = b + a` right?

The same with decreasing `i`:

```
i = 1;
i = i - i--; //Returns 0, expecting 1
```

And

```
i = 1;
i = i-- - i; //Returns 1, expecting -1
```

What confuses me even more is the usage of post increment operators:

```
i = 1;
i = i + ++i; //Returns 3
```

And

```
i = 1;
i = ++i + i; //Returns 4, expecting 3
```

Same again with decreasing operator:

```
i = 1;
i = i - --i; //Returns 1
```

And

```
i = 1;
i = --i - i; //Returns 0, expecting -1
```

**Last Question:**

How are these two lines interpreted by the compiler?

```
i = i+++i; // is it i + ++i or i++ + i?
i = i---i; // is it i - --i or i-- - i?
```

Comment: Almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13516689/11683 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3346729/11683 (last one is from Eric Lippert, must read).

Comment: `i = 1;
i = i + i++` Why do you expect `3` here?

Comment: This just goes to show that you should never use `++` and/or `--` with a variable which is also being used elsewhere in the same expression. It's too difficult to read.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Pre- & Post Increment confusions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573190/c-sharp-pre-post-increment-confusions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i = i + i++; //Returns 2, expecting 3
```

Know as post increment. Value will be used first and then incremented. It is equivalent to

```
i = i + i;
i = i+1;
```

and this is pre-increment. Value will be incremented first and then used.

```
i = i++ + i; //Returns 3
```

is equivalent to

```
i = i+1;
i = i + i;
```

> i = i+++i; // is it i + ++i or i++ + i?

is interpretted as

i = i + 1;
   i = i + i;

and this

> i = i---i; // is it i - --i or i-- - i?

is interpretted as

```
i= i-1;
i = i-i;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between pre-increment (`++i`) and post-increment (`i++`). The difference is:

Pre-increment will add the value before using the result. Post-increment will use the reslt.. then add the value. So, your first example:

```
int i;

i = 1;
i = i + i++; // First use equals 1, second use equals one. After this line though
             // i equals 2, because of your use of post-increment.
```

Likewise, your second example:

```
i = 1;
i = i++ + i; // First use is 1. After the first use.. it is incremented..
             // The second use it is 2. Therefore, 1 + 2 == 3.
```

As for your last question... why not put it into a console application and try it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Precedence of increament or decreament operator is always higher than arithmetic operators like + - * / 
Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx for details.
Also the value of postfixed increament or decreament operator is effective only after the current statement.
For eg:

```
i = i + i++ = 1 + 1++ = 1 + 1 = 2; // value of i is effective after increament is done
i = i++ + i = 1++ + 2 = 3; //Next value of i contains updated value i.e. 2
i = i + ++i = 1 + ++1 = 1 + 2 = 3; //Next value of i contains updated value i.e. 2
i = ++i + i = ++1 + i = 2 + 2; //Both value of i contains updated value i.e. 2 because of prefixed operator
i = i+++i = i++ + i;
i = i---i = i-- - i;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to try to understand this, is look at what the compiler makes of this.

See here for an overview of this for the case

```
x=i-- - --i;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8573429/959028

best regards