# Why is this integer not incrementing twice?

Tags: c#-4.0, post-increment

I am confused by the results of the code below. Why does 'b' retain a seemingly incorrect value when doing these operations?

```
        int a = 0;
        int b = 5;
        a = b++;
        b = b++;            
        Console.WriteLine("For b = b++; b=" + b.ToString()); // b should be 7 but it's 6
        a = 0;
        b = 5;
        a = b--;
        b = b--;            
        Console.WriteLine("For b = b--; b=" + b.ToString()); // b should be 3 but it's 4
        a = 0;
        b = 5;
        a = b + 1;
        b = b + 1;            
        Console.WriteLine("For b = b++; b=" + b.ToString());
```

Output

```
          b=6
          b=4
          b=6
```

Can anyone explain this behavior in C# and how it's working?

Comment: That's the behavior of the [postfix increment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691363.aspx), yes.

Comment: Most perfect answer probably here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516689/for-i-0-why-is-i-i-equal-to-0/13516748#13516748

Comment: Also, it seems fundamentally wrong to assign an increment to itself. `b = b++` does not result in `b += 1`, and `b = ++b` is a waste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's indeed the behavior of postfix operators, as detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691363.aspx).

For instance, when you write:

```
b = b++;
```

The following happens:

1. The current value of `b` is saved,
2. `b` is incremented,
3. The saved value of `b` is produced by the postfix `++` operator,
4. The value produced by the operator is assigned to `b`.

Therefore, `b` will indeed be assigned its original value, and the incremented value is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `++` and `--` operators when placed after the value will evaluate to the value itself, and then increment/decrement the value after the evaluation.

So:

```
int a = 0;
int b = a++;
```

After running this code, `b` will equal `0` and `a` will equal `1`.

This is as opposed to using the operators as prefixes:

```
int a = 0;
int b = ++a;
```

After running this code, `b` will equal `1` and `a` will equal `1`.

This is [documented behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/36x43w8w.aspx) and has been around for [a long time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators).

Answer (score 0):

The instruction a=b++ is stored on the stack but not evaluated because it was not used after that.

To get the correct result, make that instruction have a sense fro example change that line:

```
Console.WriteLine("For b = b++; b=" + b.ToString());
```

by that one:

```
Console.WriteLine("For a = b++; a=" + a.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("For b = b++; b=" + b.ToString()); //should give 7
```

Comment: are you sure it will give the value of b to 7. If i use 'a' as shown above ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
int a = 0;
int b = 5;
a = b++;
b = b++;
```

You set a to be 6, and after that you set b to be 6.
When you write b to commandline, it presents 6 because a was never used when incrementing b.
If you want to use a as well, you'd have to make

```
int a = 1;
int b = 5;
b = b++;
b += a;
Console.WriteLine("For b = a + b++; b=" + b.ToString());
```

But overall I don't see any use in this kind of incrementation.