# Difference in output of program

Tags: c#, c++, operator-precedence

I have a simple code snippets which shows different behavior when build using *C++* compiler and *C#* compiler.

**C#**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   int i = 0;
   i += i++;
   Console.WriteLine(i);
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The result of `i` is `0`.
Copied from this link. [For i = 0, why is (i += i++) equal to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516689/for-i-0-why-is-i-i-equal-to-0/13517632#13517632)

**C++**

```
int main() 
{
    int i = 0;
    i += i++;
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

The result of `i` is `1`.

I just want to know why there is difference in code output in *C#* and *C++*.

Comment: Because that expression is an undefined behavior. Another C++ compiler (or another version) may give another result.

Comment: @Adriano: It's not undefined for C#.

Comment: My guess is that C++ first evaluates the part "i++" which is one and then evaluates i+= XXX

Comment: Because it's two different languages?

Comment: Its due to the way C# handles the post-increment; The post increment operator adds one, and returns the old value. If you change it to `++i` you will get your `1` ;-)

Comment: @Dayan Means this all because c# and c++ handles post-increment differently

Comment: They're different languages.  They were written using different rules.  The designers of each language each made a different decision about how to define the semantics of those statements.

Comment: Why down votes ? If then please explain the reason for down voting

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Indeed, this is an excellent question!

Comment: @YvesDubois Thanks for your appreciation.

Comment: Remember that C# and C++ are completely different languages. They have only their name in common, and the syntax largely borrowed from C, but other than that, they aren't equal in most aspects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designers of C# and C++ and C [made different decisions about how to handle order of evaluation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/08/14/4374222.aspx) whereas in [C# the order of evaluation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa691322) if from left to right:

> Operands in an expression are evaluated from left to right.

and side effects take place from left to right as well.

In C++ this is not the case, the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `1.9` *Program execution* paragraph *15* says:

> Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced.

and if side effects on the same scalar object is sequenced relative to another side efect the result it [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

> [...]If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.[...]

and the draft gives examples of undefined behavior:

```
i = i++ + 1; // the behavior is undefined
```

which if we look at the expression from your code:

```
i += i++;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
i = i + i++ ;
```

we can now clearly see it invokes undefined behavior which means the result is unpredictable and can not be relied on.

Comment: +1 for clear picture. I accepted your answer as it has better explanation.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar if you want to learn more about undefined behavior [Why are these constructs undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-undefined-behavior) and [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) are good places to start.

Answer (score 0):

In C, an expression like `i= i++;` has an undefined behavior, and can evaluate to 0 or 1 (incrementing after evaluation of the whole expression or before the assignment are both possible).

This was a strange design decision, as apparently innocent and perfectly justified code can produce unexpected results, like `sum= a[i++] + a[i++];`. Strangely too, nobody seems to be bothered.

Comment: This is incorrect. the postfix ++ operator (ex: i++) has a very defined behavior. "++i" increments i and returns the new value, "i++" increments i and returns *the original value*.

Comment: @YvesDubois But the order of that expression with respect to other (possibly side effect inducing) expressions within the same statement is not defined.

Comment: I didn't say that ++ had an undefined behavior. I spoke of expressions containing it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: @Servy There is a very strict order in which expression are evaluated.  In both examples given, the results are in no way undefined.

Comment: Since it's undefined behavior, `int i = 0; i = i ++;` can even result in `42` as a result.  Or cause the program to crash.

Comment: @YvesDubois Where do you get that from?  The C++ (and the C) standard say exactly the opposite.

Comment: And I don't understand the down votes, since this is the correct answer.  In C and in C++, `i = i ++;` has undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the hand, @James. I did face this phenomenon years back, with MS and gnu compilers showing opposite behaviors.

Comment: @JamesKanze It's a simple matter of operation precedence. `++`has precedence over `+=` and is thus evaluated first.

Comment: @YvesDubois It has nothing to do with precedence.  The C++
standard says explicitly that the behavior is undefined.  (See
§5/4 in C++03.)  It always has---this goes back to the earliest
days of C.

Comment: @JamesKanze Have any link to a copy?

Comment: Okay, I just got an epiphany and finally understand what the problem is. To say the result is undefined is a bit of an exaggeration, after `int i=0; i+=i++;`, `i` will always be equal to 0 or 1. It depends if the `+` operator is constructed to work as `operator+(int a, int b)` or `operator+(const int& a, const int& b)`. In the first case, the left-hand side is evaluated as 0 before the right-hand side (`i++`) is evaluated. In the second case the left-hand side is evaluated as "the variable i", thus the code uses it's current value. And if I'm to believe you **this is not standardized!?**

Comment: It is explicitly standardized as being undefined behavior.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I guess they don't want to mess around with possible compiler optimizations. After all, it's not as if standardizing it would break legacy code. (unless it depended on undefined behaviour)

Comment: For safety, compilers should raise warnings when such constructs are used. It is not always the case.

Comment: @YvesDubois It's not normally available for free, but I believe that there are some unofficial copies (probably of the final draft) floating around on the net.  (I got mine because I was a "technical expert" for AFNOR.)

Comment: @JamesKanze as far as I know this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) links to all the publicly available draft standards. For the most part you can usually get pretty close to the official standard.