# Unpredicted language behavior i++

Tags: c#, .net, post-increment, pre-increment

I tried to do the following

```
i=0;
if (i++ % Max_Col_items == 0 && i !=0)
{

}
```

and discovered that it increased `i` in the middle

```
i % Max_Col_items == 0;
i=i+1;
i !=0;
```

when I though it would add increase `i` in the end:

```
i % Max_Col_items == 0;
i !=0;
i=i+1;
```

Can any one find explanation of how `i++` works in C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between X = X++; vs X++;?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226002/whats-the-difference-between-x-x-vs-x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i++` will give you the original value, not the incremented, You will see the change on the next usage of `i`. If you want to get the incremented value then use `++i`.

See the detailed answer by [Eric Lippert on the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3346729/961113)

Comment: The OP has made it clear what he expected to happen and what he has observed happening. He doesn't _want_ the incremented value; he wants to know why the value is incremented by the second part of his `&&`.

Comment: @Rawling, thats what I said, Change will be visible on the next usage of `i`

Comment: Eventually, yes. Your original answer just said that `i++` gives the original value and use `++i` if you want the original value, which was irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Rawling, I was in the middle of editing and trying to find the answer by Eric lippert, but thats ok

Answer (score 0):

`i++` immediately increments the value of `i` but evaluates as the value before incrementation.

It doesn't leave the value of `i` untouched until the end of the line of code, which appears to be what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

That is because (as you have rightly noted)

i % Max_Col_items == 0;

is an operation in itself. Once that line of operation is over (with value of i ) the increment is done.