# unary increment operator i++ in C#

Tags: c#, unary-operator

In my last interview i found this tricky question.
after these two lines what will be the value of i.

```
int i=c;
//c is a constant
i=i++;
```

where c is a constant(where c is initialised before). please give me step by step answer rather than one word answer.

Comment: If its C#, then why Java is tagged ?

Comment: Did you even bother to try to run the code? The question is addressed by section 7.6.9 of the C# 5.0 specification, but if all you want to know is what the code will do, it's silly to post a question here. You can just run it yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between X = X++; vs X++;?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226002/whats-the-difference-between-x-x-vs-x)

Comment: @PeterDuniho more specifically i need explanation

Comment: You need a better explanation than already exists in the duplicate question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally value of i remains same as c.

Explanation:-
when i is assigned with *i++*;

step 1. first i++ return value c(but not assigned to left-hand operand i).

step 2. then i++ increments value of i to c+1.

step 3. i is assigned with value c that is returned in step1.

> In effect value of i remains same but some where along the execution it
>   was c+1, But finally it is assigned with value c.