# Possible incorrect operators priority

Tags: java, c#

Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
int x = 10;
int y = 10;

x = x + x++;
y = y++ + y;

print(x); // 20
print(y); // 21
```

C-like programming languages like C# or Java say that increment has higher precedence, than `+` operator. So it should be `21` in both cases.

Why does it print two different results?

Comment: This might clear things up for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226002/whats-the-difference-between-x-x-vs-x

Comment: Take a look at the difference between ++x and x++. That should answer your question.

Comment: I believe this may help a lot: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order.aspx

Comment: This is not a question about the difference between ++i and i++, it is about operators precedence.

Comment: "Higher precedence" means that `++` is attached to `x` instead of to `+`; it does _not_ mean it's evaluated first.

Comment: It's mainly due the associativity of the evaluation which is left to right.

Comment: @OrelEraki Thank you. The best answer here.

Answer (score 7):

Remember we work from left to right.

Let's deal with x first then y.

### x

x = x + x++;

We are going from left to right...

x = 10 + (10++)

Note: As we go from left to right the post increment operator on x on the far right has no effect on the x which appears first on the RHS.

x = 20

### y

y = y++ + y;

y = 10++ + 11;

Again we go from left to right, the increment operator post increments y from 10 to 11, hence the y on the far right becomes 11, thus yielding (10 + 11) = 21.

Comment: Operators priority says that we must always start with increment and only then do addition. It does not depend on order from left to right.

Comment: Why i compiled the example in C and the result was `21,21` ?

Comment: @klimenkov you are mistaking order of evaluation and precedence

Comment: @JeanJung C does not declare rules how to evaluate expressions. But Java and C# do.

Comment: @klimenkov oh, sorry, my mistake. That's true. When i have read the question was clearly true that the behavior is because the operands analyze orders, i posted an answer and then i deleted it when i have seen the C results. I have forgot that C does not implies rules of precedence.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `+` operator has higher precedence than `++`, so the `+` operator is evaluated first, but in order to evaluate it - it must evaluate the left and right operators of it.

In the second example the left operator is evaluated first so `y` increments before the right hand is evaluated.

---

In the [Precedence and Order of Evaluation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx) documentation, you can see that `+` is above `+=` which is basically what `++` is. Above the `+` is the **prefix** `++` which is not to be confused with the **postfix** `++`.

Answer (score 0):

When `y++ + y` is evaluated, `y++` is evaluated before `y`. So the left hand side is evaluated to 10, and the right hand side will be evaluated to 11 due to the previous incrementation.
When `x + x++` is evaluated, `x` is evaluated before `x++`. So both sides will be evaluated to 10, then `x` will be evaluated to 11 just before the `=` operand will evaluate `x` to 20.