# Why is increment a bit complicated?

Tags: c#

Why is that

```
x = 10, y = 10;
z = x++ + y++;
```

Is still **20**? They have increment both but the output is still **20** why? But when i do this

```
z = ++x + ++y;
```

the output became **22**. Why and how??? Someone can explain it to me? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between X = X++; vs X++;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226002/whats-the-difference-between-x-x-vs-x)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#increment-operator-

Comment: There are two types of increment: `x++` increments `x` and returns *initial* value; `++x` increments `x` and returns *new* (incremented) value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346450/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i/3346729#3346729 is worth a read.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of ++x and x++ as follows

```
static int x_plus_plus(ref int x)
{
  int xp = x;
  x = x+1;
  return xp;
}

static int plus_plus_x(ref int x)
{
  x = x+1;
  return x;
}
```

Now, when you do x++ + y++, the values of x and y are increased by 1 but the x++ *returns old* x value,
in case of ++x, x is increased by 1 plus (++x) makes use of the *new value* of x.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this description by Microsoft [Arithmetic operators (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators)

and this two examples:

i++ completes the operation first (returning its value) and increments then:

```
int i = 3;
Console.WriteLine(i);   // output: 3
Console.WriteLine(i++); // output: 3
Console.WriteLine(i);   // output: 4
```

While in this example (++a) the value is incrememented first and then returned.

```
double a = 1.5;
Console.WriteLine(a);   // output: 1.5
Console.WriteLine(++a); // output: 2.5
Console.WriteLine(a);   // output: 2.5
```